# Python development dependencies

Tags: python, dependency-management

I'm familiar with installing dependencies using a `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml`, but I've only ever seen syntax in those files like `some_package>=1.2.3`.

What does it mean when dependencies are listed with curly braces, as in:

```
pytest = "^6.2.5"
coverage = {extras = ["toml"], version = "^5.5"}
safety = "^1.10.3"
mypy = "^0.910"
typeguard = "^2.12.1"
xdoctest = {extras = ["colors"], version = "^0.15.5"}
Sphinx = "^4.1.2"
sphinx-autobuild = "^2021.3.14"
```

and how do you install those dependences?

Trying to install those by treating the file as a `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml` throws an `ERROR: Invalid requirement` or `CondaValueError: invalid package specification`, respectively.

Comment: seems like you need `poetry`:
https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/

Comment: @vagitus, you figured it out!  Want to post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python-poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#dependency-extras) uses that format for defining dependencies in a `pyproject.toml` file usually under `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`

As explained by [PEP 508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/) packages can have **extra dependencies** which enables optional features of a given package (package dependent).

You could [install poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) and use that to manage dependencies or transform that list into a valid format that conda or pip understands.

For example the dependency list for pip would look like this:

```
pytest>=6.2.5
coverage[toml]>=5.5
safety>=1.10.3
mypy>=0.910
typeguard>=2.12.1
xdoctest[colors]>=0.15.5
Sphinx>=4.1.2
sphinx-autobuild>=2021.3.14
```